# Automating Role Assignment in Multiple Subscriptions

Tags: azure, powershell

I have multiple subscription names in the text file and i am looking to assign a role to a group on all those subscription in Azure. I am trying, the below PS code but it is working only for the subscription name mentioned at the first but not for all.

Need help in the code to assign the role to a group on all the subscriptions in the text file

```
$SubscriptionName = Get-Content “C:\temp\subscriptions.txt”

foreach ($Subscription in $SubscriptionName)
{
   $sub = get-AzureRmSubscription -Subscriptionname $Subscription
}

$groupID = (Get-AzureRmADGroup -SearchString “SG-testing-Contributor”).Id

New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $groupID -Scope “/subscriptions/$($sub.SubscriptionId)” -RoleDefinitionName “Contributor”

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra closing bracket. This should run it for each subscription name:

```bsh
$SubscriptionName = Get-Content “C:\temp\subscriptions.txt”

foreach ($Subscription in $SubscriptionName) {
    $sub = Get-AzSubscription -Subscriptionname $Subscription
    $groupID = (Get-AzADGroup -SearchString "SG-testing-Contributor").Id
    New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $groupID -Scope "/subscriptions/$($sub.SubscriptionId)" -RoleDefinitionName Contributor
}
```